# Creating a Bash script to modify tty port permissions

Tags: shell-script, centos, permissions, tty, serial-port

I am trying to create a Bash script that will run on system startup and modify the permissions for a number of ttyA ports. I'm unsure how to go about this and was wondering if I could get some help.

My current code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
TTYA=$ ls /dev/ttyA11

echo $TTYA

echo 'outside'
if [[ $$TTYA == 'ttyA11' ]]
then
  echo 'inside' 
  chmod g+rw /dev/ttyA*
fi
```

Output:

```
$ sudo ./rc.serial
/dev/ttyA11

outside
```

Unfortunately this method does not work due to the `if` statement not being true. I'm unsure if I've correctly told my variable to check for `ttyA11`.

Comment: Why not add your users to `plugdev` group instead?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's possible to create a bash script that will execute my command on a number of ports. I'm not aware of `plugdev`, but I do know my `ttyA` ports need to be assigned to the `dialout` group.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dialout` group of course.

Comment: That's ok. I just know that I need to be able to replicate these two commands: `chmod g+rw /dev/ttyA*` and `chgrp dialout /dev/ttyA*` in a bash script that I will run during system startup. I'm certain there's an efficient way to do this that my current listed method. But I'm new to Bash scripting and only have a very tiny amount of knowledge on this

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you want to do. Do you want to check if `/dev/ttyA11` exists?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The `ttyA11` port is loaded by a driver every time the system loads however it has the wrong permissions and group set. So to combat this I would like to make a script file that updates the permissions and group accordingly when the system starts up. I don't want to keep updating the permissions manually every time I restart my machine basically. Hope this helps?

Comment: On Linux, one would normally use a `udev` rule to set the group aan mode when the device is loaded - see for example [Allow non-root user to read/write /dev files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111593/allow-non-root-user-to-read-write-dev-files)

Comment: @steeldriver I had seen something about udev in a forum post. Thank you for providing a link and through reading the solution listed here I was able to successfully make a udev rule. The file is just rather large now with over 40 lines of individual port rules haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your script that need attention.

```
TTYA=$ ls /dev/ttyA11
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but if you do `TTYA=$(ls /dev/ttyA11)` (note the correct syntax for assigning the output of a command to a variable), `TTYA` wil contain `/dev/ttyA11`, if that device exists.

```
echo $TTYA
```

You should probably put quotes here, as in `echo "$TTYA"`

```
echo 'outside'
if [[ $$TTYA == 'ttyA11' ]]
```

`$$` will expand to the PID of  the running shell. So, the if-statement will always be false. If you use `$TTYA` (single dollar), the statement will also be false, because `TTYA` has a `/dev/` in front of the device name.

```
then
  echo 'inside' 
  chmod g+rw /dev/ttyA*
fi
```

The logic of the script is strange; it looks like you want to make `/dev/ttyA*` group-rw if `/dev/ttyA11` exists. But in that case, would

```
if [ -e  /dev/ttyA11 ] ; then
   chmod g+rw /dev/ttyA*
fi
```

be more logic?

Comment: Thank you for providing me a detailed insight into the matter. Honestly I wasn't sure what I was attempting there, but after reading your solution it makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TTYA='ls /dev/ttyA11'

eval $TTYA

echo $TTYA

echo "outside"

if [ $TTYA == 'ttyA11' ]

then
  
 echo "inside"
  
 chmod g+rw /dev/ttyA*

fi
```

Comment: This will produce `bash: [: too many arguments`, because `TTYA` contains `ls /dev/ttyA11` (so, with a space in it). Shellcheck will tell you that you must quote $TTYA, but even then, the `if` condition will always be false.